# implementation of slider in Google glass which is displayed in volume control option

Tags: slider, implementation

I want to implement the slider bar in google glass, which is existing in the volume control option in google glass, can any one let me know how can i implement this, i have tried using seek bar which doesn't work.

Thanks & Regards.
Nagendra

Answer (score 2):

You have to use GestureDetector for this. Have your activity's `onCreate` as follows.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGestureDetector = createGestureDetector(this);
}
```

When you scroll/swipe, the `onScroll` below will be called. You can interpret the output in anyway you want. I generally use only the `delta` and ignore the rest.

```
private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context);

    gestureDetector.setScrollListener(new GestureDetector.ScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(float displacement, float delta, float velocity) {
            // This is a crude way to estimate the scale size
            int scaleFactor = (int) delta/10;

            doStuff(scaleFactor);

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```